# string to a method class

Tags: c#, string, class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string name= "noName";
      name= Console.ReadLine();
      person kalle = new person();
}

class person
{
    static string name;
    int age;

    public void setName(string n)
    {
        name= n;
    }
}
```

So how can I change "kalle" to a string named "name" so the user of the program can decide wot the person will be called?

**I can clarify what I want to do:**That i am looking for is so i can decide the name to whatever the user want instead of "kalle" so change "kalle" to a string...

Comment: `kalle` is a person so you can't change them into a string.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Looks like you are missing some of the code.

Comment: Can you explain what you want more understandable?

Comment: You want the *variable name* `kalle` to change? That is not how variable names work.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues with the current version of the code.

- `name` is a static field inside `Person` which associates it with the `Person` type and not instances.  Remove the `static` modifier so each `Person` can have their own name
- The default visibility of C# members is `private` which means no one can access `name` or `age`.  They should be `internal` or `public`
- In general you should prefer properties over fields

Here is the code with the proposed changes

```
class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

...

string name = "noName";
name = Console.ReadLine();
person kalle = new person();
kalle.name = name;
```

Comment: You could also leave it private and use `setName`

Comment: @Blorgbeard this is C# though and not Java. I would use properties (new code sample does) vs. explicit `getName` / `setName` methods

Comment: I can clarify what I want to do:That i am looking for is so i can decide the name to whatever the user want instead of "kalle" so change "kalle" to a string...

Comment: @JaredPar that's true - then perhaps remove setName from your proposed code?

Comment: @Blorgbeard doh, I answered this question before I finished my first coffee.  I read right past that and thought it was a ctor not a `setName` method.  I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `static` modifier to the field `string name` in class `person` after call `kalle.setName(name)` in your program.

Comment: the variable name is visible only in your local application block... this is not the name of the person object but only the name of a local variable. So why do you think the user of your program want to change it ?

Answer (score 1):

Override `ToString()`, somethign like this:

```
class Person
    {
        .....
        .....
       public override string ToString() {
            return name;
       }
    }
```

So you can do:

```
person kalle = new person();
kalle.name = "Hello"; 
string value = falle.ToString();
```

So the `kalle`'s string rapresentation *here*, becomes "Hello" (the content of `name` property)

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

**EDIT**

An example of reading more then one

```
string s = null;
while((s = Console.ReadLine())!="x") {
    Console.WriteLine("how many people would you add?"); 
    int howMany = Console.ReadLine();
    for(int i=0;i<howMany ;i++) 
    {

       //create Person objects and add them to the collection

       //ask user to insert the name for current Person
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Please insert the name for the Person {0}", i));

      //read the name
      string name = Console.ReadLine();

      //construct Person object, based on (i) and (name)
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you're asking for.

Comment: That i am looking for is so i can decide the name to whatever the user want instead of "kalle".

Comment: @kalle: may be I understood. You want that somehow the user instead of  kalle.name can write "Hello".name ?? If, so: it's impossible.

Comment: okay but is there any way that in an if statement so i can get a user specified number of persons??

Comment: @flamme: please provide witha small code example, not really understand what do you mean.

Comment: `        Console.WriteLine("how many people would you add?");
         int howMany = Console.ReadLine(); ` and and with "for" repeating and doing so that it can be x number of people who I later can give names, etc to

Comment: @flaimme: check my edited post, hope this is what you're asking for.

Comment: well thanks, but how do I do "create Person objects and add them to the collection" part wen they ned when they need to have different names?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to dynamically set the name of the instance?

So you've got

```
person kalle = new person()
```

If the user enters "sven" you would get

```
person sven = new person()
```

??

Comment: Yes there is such a class as I would like to have but it."kalle" is just to show what/where I mean.

Comment: Can't be done that I'm aware of. Tigran's suggestion is as close as you'll get. You could have a loop that adds each new user to a List<Person> or some other collection, that way you don't have to specify an instance name but you can still easily access each of the instances.